# The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: php, mysql

php showing me this error when i try to connect to database

```
$bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php','root','Projet_');
```

i tried

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Projet_';
```

but it's giving me mysql error 1805 expected 51 found 48 in mysql.user